# How to make a simple network bridge in Vagrant?

Tags: networking, bridge, vagrant, arp

I'm trying do set up the most basic network bridge demo in Vagrant. I have two machines in the same subnet, but on different LANs, and a bridge machine with two interfaces and a network bridge that gets set up in a provisioning script.

Here's my `Vagrantfile`:

```
$bridge_script = <<SCRIPT
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y bridge-utils
sudo brctl addbr br0
sudo brctl addif br0 eth1 eth2
sudo ifconfig br0 up
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.define "machine1" do |machine1|
    machine1.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
    machine1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.1.2",
      virtualbox__intnet: "lan1"
  end

  config.vm.define "bridge" do |bridge|
    bridge.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
    bridge.vm.network "private_network", ip: "0.0.0.0",
      virtualbox__intnet: "lan1"
    bridge.vm.network "private_network", ip: "0.0.0.0",
      virtualbox__intnet: "lan2"
    bridge.vm.provision :shell, inline: $bridge_script
  end

  config.vm.define "machine2" do |machine2|
    machine2.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
    machine2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.1.3",
      virtualbox__intnet: "lan2"
  end
end
```

I can't get either machine to ping the other successfully. Using `tcpdump` I found that an ARP request get passed from `machine1` all the way to `machine2`, but when `machine2` responds, the response does not even get to `eth2` on `bridge`. (I only see the ARP response when listening on `eth1` in  `machine2`.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that by default VirtualBox doesn't let you have promiscuous NICs, you have to explicitly enable it.

I added the following lines to the `bridge` definition and things started to work:

```
bridge.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nicpromisc2", "allow-all"]
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nicpromisc3", "allow-all"]
end
```